# Как массово обрезать фотографии снизу на 20 пикселей?

Tags: изображения

Как массово обрезать 3 тыс. фотографий снизу на 20 пикселей?
Фотошоп сильно тупит, хотя системные показатели средние.

Comment: На python с подойдёт? Я с ватермарками вполне удачно справился. Но если на раз, то вполне какой-то редактор вроде FarStone может вполне подойти для решения вопроса.

Comment: @BlayWille да, можно сказать, что "на раз". Phyton'ом не владею, хотелось бы что-либо с гибким кадрированием. В FastStone, если я правильно разобрался, можно сделать кадрирование в целом, т.е. "съестся" и верх и низ (нужен только низ)

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/r7a0jSY.png  нужен только низ, тогда подбираете размер, в процентах или в фиксированной ширине